# Issue in node js code when using await calls

Tags: node.js, async-await

In the Node.js functions shown below - the function main returns a list of orders. In the  `initialDocs2.push(orderIdString)` I see the list of all order IDs which will be processed. Then there is an async operation of getting transaction from the DB for the order. The problem is after fetching the transaction I am pushing the orders into another array called  `procsseddocs.push(orderIdString)` in which I am getting duplicate values of orderId (though no dupes in the `initialDocs2`). Why is this happening?

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
initialDocs2 = []
procsseddocs = []
txnarr = []
async function main() {
    const url = "<connectionstring>"
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
    let target_db = "<db>"

    totalDocCount = 0;
    cabCount = 0;
    dutyFreeCount = 0;
    flightBookingCount = 0;
    pranaamCount = 0;
    try {
        await client.connect();
        target_db = client.db(target_db);
        initialdocs = []
        await target_db.collection("order").find().forEach(async function (doc) {
            totalDocCount++;
            if (doc._id) {
                if (doc.businessSubType == "FlightBooking") {
                    flightBookingCount++;
                    try {
                        initialdocs.push(String(doc._id))
                        flightBookingTransform(target_db, doc);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log("Errored in flight booking free transform:", doc._id, " error:", e)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        )
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
async function flightBookingTransform(target_db, docOrder) {
    try {
        orderIdString = String(docOrder._id)
        initialDocs2.push(orderIdString)
        docTransactionarr = await target_db.collection("transaction").find({
            "orderId.oid": orderIdString
        }).sort({
            "_id": -1
        }).limit(1).toArray()

        if (docTransactionarr && docTransactionarr.length > 0)
            docTransaction = docTransactionarr[0]
        else
            return
        txnarr.push(String(docTransaction._id))
        procsseddocs.push(orderIdString)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Something went wrong", e)
    }
};
main()
```

Comment: You mean you have duplicates in `procsseddocs` but not in `initalDocs2`? I don't see how that would be possible with your code. I could understand the other way around if something between the two pushes threw an exception. But that what you describe here is possible only if you manipulate `processeddocs` in some other code which you don't show here ...

Comment: I thought so too - but it is happening! I was able to resolve it by changing from forEach to to for await in the calling side